# Did the Yeerk or Goa'uld influence each other?

Tags: stargate, animorphs, goauld, yeerks

The Yeerk from *Animorphs* and the Goa'uld from *Stargate* seem overbearingly similar. They were both introduced within a year of each other. Has there been any reference from anyone assoicated with either franchise that they used the other as inspiration?

Similarities:

- Parasitic aliens who take completely control of a host
- They both rule the galaxy
- They were both given the opportunity to progress by a more advanced species (Asgard, Andalites)
- Both have a peaceful, symbiotic "good" offshoots (Tok'ra, Yoort)

There are many more similarities. The only differences seem to be that Yeerks need to leave the host every 3 days to recharge and that Goa'uld attach to the spine rather than the brain.

Is there any reason to think that one influenced the creation of the other?

Comment: See also the Nomads from Freelancer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's very unlikely. The notion of a parasite controlling a host goes back decades in science fiction writing, and alien invasions similarly - the basic scheme in film goes back to *Invasion of the Body Snatchers* and in prose probably earlier. A key example is [*From Within*, the 1995 Outer Limits S2E13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/From_Within_(The_Outer_Limits)") was written in 1996, prior to the publication of *Animorphs*.

> Miners unearth ancient parasites, in the shape of worms, that attack the brains of their hosts, entering through the nose or ears. While the infected townsfolk lose all their inhibitions,

The writer for that episode was Jonathan Glassner, co-creator of *Stargate SG-1*.

Comment: Going back to 1951, there's the Heinlein book "The Puppet Masters"